# Install dotnet-ef tool

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to install dotnet-ef on my development machine I just installed Visual Studio 2022,when I run the command dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 6.0.3
I get the following error

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\l3bki0v4.vtr\restore.csproj(5,31): error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'dotnet-ef' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

- You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
- A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
- The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
- You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
How can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

Probably .Net6 SDK is not installed. Please open VS installer and check Installed  components .

[image: VS Installer]
click on modify and check .Net SDK option checked in individual components Tab.
[image: individual components tab]

Comment: .NET SDK is installed